# Will running another OS On virtualbox slow my computer down after I have stopped it?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

If I install another OS, say Ubuntu 17.10 on virtualbox will it slow down my computer at all?  Will there be any noticable difference even after I turn off the vm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no, respectively.

To your computer, Virtualbox running a Virtual Machine will use resources similar to a large application, and, depending on the amount of memory and CPU units assigned to the virtual machine and how many of these resources your computer has to begin with, those resources will no longer be available to the host.

When the VM is shut off it is no longer using any system resources besides disk space, and will therefore not slow your computer down unless you are very low on that.

Comment: So if I shut down virtualbox, there won't be a noticable difference in performance on my computer?  I'm fine with a difference while I'm running the vm, as it would be accessing resources on my host os and my guest os.  I just want to make sure it won't slow my computer down when I'm not using it and it's shut down.

Comment: That is what I said. In the same way a program that is not running does not use system resources besides disk space.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help! I'll accept your answer as soon as superuser let's me.